# Symfony2 ACL Cache

Tags: caching, symfony, acl

Is there any example or better documentation about how to cache ACL Queries in Symfony2.

I found following:

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Domain/DoctrineAclCache.html

But i do not exactly know how to apply this on my Checks.

Comment: hm that's an interesting one. investigating ...

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to cache ObjectIdentities. Which is bit of a help but not much.

After a lot of digging around in the security*.xml files I've made the following modifications of the config.yml:

- I've added cache id (Service id) to the ACL configuration
- I've enabled Doctrine result cache.

config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        result_cache_driver:
            type: apc

security:
    acl:
        cache:
            id:     security.acl.cache.doctrine
            prefix: my_acl_prefix_
```

This will only enable caching of ObjectIdentities, but a lot of other queries are happening when the `Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Dbal\AclProvider::getAncestorIds()` is being called. That method directly executes an SQL query, and uses no cache. In 2.2 and 2.3 there is a comment in the method saying:

```
            // FIXME: skip ancestors which are cached
```

Same stands for a couple of other methods in that class in terms of not using result cache.

I guess by implementing your own AclProvider and injecting the entity manager's result cache you can cache these queries too.